# How to import events from wallet to calendar?

Tags: ios, calendar, wallet

Is there a way to import tickets/events from wallet to calendar in ios?
This seems to be a very basic functionality but still hard to figure out.

I know wallet shows notifications but having all of my events in my calendar gives me a better overall look on my plans.

Comment: this is not possible today.